# needed in a foreign key constraint error by doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-3.4

I have database project migration from Symfony 3.2 -> 3.4

I made new project and copy entity to the new 3.4 environment.

then,

`php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force`

it shows the error.

```
  An exception occurred while executing 'DROP INDEX IDX_EFE42E9BC5E35EFC ON placeinfos_placecats':                   

  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1553 Cannot drop index 'IDX_EFE42E9BC5E35EFC': needed in a foreign key constraint
```

So, I am checking the placeinfos_placecats table,

```
mysql> show create table placeinfos_placecats;

| placeinfos_placecats | CREATE TABLE `placeinfos_placecats` (
  `placeinfo_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `placecat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`placeinfo_id`,`placecat_id`),
  KEY `IDX_EFE42E9BC5E35EFC` (`placecat_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_EFE42E9B6762112` FOREIGN KEY (`placeinfo_id`) REFERENCES `PlaceInfo` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_EFE42E9BC5E35EFC` FOREIGN KEY (`placecat_id`) REFERENCES `PlaceCat` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |
```

There is constraint `IDX_EFE42E9BC5E35EFC`.

And then, what the doctrine tries to do,

`php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql`

```
 DROP INDEX IDX_EFE42E9BC5E35EFC ON placeinfos_placecats;
 DROP INDEX IDX_EFE42E9B6762112 ON placeinfos_placecats;
 ALTER TABLE placeinfos_placecats DROP PRIMARY KEY;
 ALTER TABLE placeinfos_placecats ADD place_info_id INT NOT NULL, ADD place_cat_id INT NOT NULL, DROP placeinfo_id, DROP placecat_id;
 ALTER TABLE placeinfos_placecats ADD CONSTRAINT FK_EFE42E9B6947D603 FOREIGN KEY (place_info_id) REFERENCES place_info (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
 ALTER TABLE placeinfos_placecats ADD CONSTRAINT FK_EFE42E9B4463AE2A FOREIGN KEY (place_cat_id) REFERENCES place_cat (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
 CREATE INDEX IDX_EFE42E9B6947D603 ON placeinfos_placecats (place_info_id);
 CREATE INDEX IDX_EFE42E9B4463AE2A ON placeinfos_placecats (place_cat_id);
 ALTER TABLE placeinfos_placecats ADD PRIMARY KEY (place_info_id, place_cat_id);
 ALTER TABLE fos_user DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_957A6479B6E0899D;
 ALTER TABLE fos_user CHANGE userkey user_key VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL;
 ALTER TABLE fos_user ADD CONSTRAINT FK_957A6479B6E0899D FOREIGN KEY (metainfo_id) REFERENCES meta_info (id);
 ALTER TABLE media__gallery_media DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_80D4C5414E7AF8F;
 ALTER TABLE media__gallery_media DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_80D4C541EA9FDD75;
 ALTER TABLE media__gallery_media ADD CONSTRAINT FK_80D4C5414E7AF8F FOREIGN KEY (gallery_id) REFERENCES media__gallery (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
 ALTER TABLE media__gallery_media ADD CONSTRAINT FK_80D4C541EA9FDD75 FOREIGN KEY (media_id) REFERENCES media__media (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
 DROP INDEX IDX_5C6DD74E12469DE2 ON media__media;
 ALTER TABLE media__media DROP category_id;
```

What does it mean???
Just dropping and adding constraint again??

Why doctrine wants to do like this ?

Then ,how should I solve it??

Comment: it would help if you showed the entities in question with the doctrine annotations

Comment: as far as I can tell, the orderings in queries from the schema-tool have been off for ages now, especially with foreign keys involved. to your question: yes, dropping the foreign key constraint first and later adding it again will help. other option would be to actually do proper migrations ...

Answer (score 1):

I just deleted the table manually via adminer. Withot "foreign key check".

Then, I did `bin/console doctrine:schema:update -f` and its ok!

I suppose this closely connected with Foreign Key restrictions. So, you can somehow exclude this check in doctrine.
[image]

But be careful. I guess method below isn't really good way for prod.

Actually, you could delete a special KEYNAME via adminer!

IDX_EFE42E9BC5E35EFC, for example...

[image]